# Sharepoint online list, calculated value not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

On sharepoint online, for a custom list that contains single line of texts columns, i'm trying a simple calculated formula.

```
=if(1=1,"123")
```

This fails with SharePoint online error "formula contains errors"

if i try the following:

```
="1123"
```

it works.

So if i put any IF then it fails.
obviously i need something more complex, as a 12 nested if or and.. but if this basic doesn't work then i can't advance.

Answer (score 1):

Basic syntax for IF statement in calculated formula is:

```
IF(logical_test,value_if_true,value_if_false)
```

So, try to write down your formula in above format.

**Sources**:

1. [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a)
2. [SharePoint: Creating Calculated Column Formulas the Easy Way Using Excel](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2010/08/sharepoint-creating-calculated-column.html?m=1).

The second link is very helpful while creating calculated column formula's in SharePoint.

**Note**:

Sometimes comma(,) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language on your site). So in that case use semicolon(;) instead of comma(,).

Comment: Have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=IF(1=1;123)
```

Use " ; " instead of " , ".

Answer (score 0):

Tried this:

```
 =IF(Type_Reseau="Eau domestique 70 PSI et moins",IF(Type_Essai="Hydrostatique","2 Heures"),IF(Type_Reseau="Eau domestique 70 PSI et moins",IF(Type_Essai="Pneumatique","1 Heure","ERROR")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is:

```
=IF(AND(Type_Reseau="Eau domestique 70 PSI et moins";Type_Essai="Hydrostatique");"2 Heures";
IF(AND(Type_Reseau="Eau domestique 70 PSI et moins";Type_Essai="Pneumatique");"1 Heure";
IF(AND(Type_Reseau="Eau domestique 71@115 PSI";Type_Essai="Hydrostatique");"2 heures";
IF(AND(Type_Reseau="Eau domestique 71@115 PSI";Type_Essai="Pneumatique");"1 heure";
IF(AND(Type_Reseau="Chauffage et eau refroidie";Type_Essai="Hydrostatique");"2 heures";
IF(AND(Type_Reseau="Chauffage et eau refroidie";Type_Essai="Pneumatique");"1 heure";
IF(AND(Type_Reseau="Drainage sanitaire, pluvial, pompé et évent";Type_Essai="Hydrostatique");"15 minutes";
IF(AND(Type_Reseau="Drainage sanitaire, pluvial, pompé et évent";Type_Essai="Fumée");"15 minutes";
IF(AND(Type_Reseau="Gaz naturel";Type_Essai="Hydrostatique");"ERREUR";
IF(AND(Type_Reseau="Gaz naturel";Type_Essai="Pneumatique");"3 heures"
))))))))))
```