# IF statement with text field isn't possible?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, calculated-column-formula

Trying to do formula `=IF([FIELD1]=[FIELD2],1)`. When I try to save the formula it gives me **syntax error**. Is it possible to achieve this with text?

The reason behind that is if texts match it would give 1 if doesn't then 0 after I would be calculating `=SUM([Fields])`.

**Update**:

I got a new problem now. Trying to separate text from numbers.

The Formula I am using:

```
=LEFT(Antraštė);SUM(LEN([Antraštė]-LEN(SUBSITUTE([Antraštė];{"0";"1";"2";"3";"4";"5";"6";"7";"8";"9"};"""))))
```

and it keeps getting **syntax error**.

Comment: The problem was with comma instead of =IF([Field1]=[Field2], 1) I had to write =IF([Field1]=[Field2]; 1) that fixed it

Comment: You should do a new question for the new issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic syntax for IF statement in calculated formula is:

```
IF(logical_test,value_if_true,value_if_false)
```

So, try to write down your formula in above format.

**Note**:

Sometimes comma(,) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language on your site). So in that case use semicolon(;) instead of comma(,).

For detailed information and references check my answer given in below link:

[Sharepoint online list, calculated value not working](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/256868/sharepoint-online-list-calculated-value-not-working/256874#256874)

Comment: I found out that myself but thank you for informative response